# Best way to keep anonymity inside a VM

Tags: anonymity, ip-spoofing, vmware

If I use a proxy shield inside a VM and spoof my IP address, is there any possibility that someone else ( victim ) can identify the host machine's IP and other details?

What is the best way that we can use to keep our anonymity inside a VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I use a proxy shield inside a VM and spoof my IP address, is there
>   any possibility that someone else ( victim ) can identify the host
>   machine's IP and other details?

Yes. Except very specific cases in a LAN (no routers in the middle), your VM will still be "seen" from the outside as belonging to your system, the one that is *running* the VM. There is no difference between the program running the VM and any other program (why should there be?).

It might be easier to setup a VM with, say, Linux than deploying some "attack tool" that forges packets as if they came from a Linux box. Also, a VM would be more "coherent" - you wouldn't need to be careful against slips. So for the purpose of modeling an attack, a VM is better.

In the above case of a LAN, a VM with a "bridged" interface is almost indistinguishable from a separate machine altogether (again, barring higher end setups in which you're connected with a smart switch. The switch *knows* - or strongly suspects - that your VM is actually *you*, or that you know more than you should about that VM). So to prank your room-mate a VM is great, and you can prank a co-worker as well, as long as you don't work somewhere that has a separate, competent and equipped IT department.

> What is the best way that we can use to keep our anonymity inside a VM?

You are not asking about *anonymity* but *untraceability* (they're slightly different things, and the latter does improve the former). Anonymity is more depending on your infrastructure, so a VM is a good way of going about it; my own choice would be to run as close to a stock install of the most common OS you can find, with no personal information stored on it *ever*.

Untraceability is more related to the communication infrastructure, so you're talking VPN or SSH tunnels, overseas shell hosts, and (ab)using other people's open WiFis.

For example I'm now connected through a double SSH tunnel and the machine in the middle keeps no logs whatsoever. Unless someone succeeds in breaking into that machine or its serving routers and see where my connection comes from, I'm *untraceable*. I might be literally anywhere. But I'm voluntarily logged with my username, so I'm definitely **not** "anonymous".

On my own home PC I've a Windows 7 VM identical to one hundred million others, and my name isn't anywhere in it. While I do connect from my home ADSL (so I'm *traceable*), that connection is *anonymous* for anyone except (perhaps) law enforcement and governments.

(And if you're up against anything like *that*, keep in mind that cryptography and digital anonymity [may not work the way you think](https://xkcd.com/538/)).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I learned a lot about this !

Answer (score 1):

Your VM can be thought of as a part of your system or a separate interface on it depending on how you configure it.

If it's configured to share the host's IP, then all the traffic sent out will exit from your host effectively negating its use. If you choose to assign it a separate IP, then identifying your host system would be a little more difficult.

Using a VM to stay *anonymous* isn't really of much use. At the most, it'll prevent your host from (except for sandbox exploits) being fingerprinted completely.

The best way IMO would be to encrypt all your traffic, use noscript in your browser, Tor with a VPN and so on.

**tl;dr**: Using a VM does *not* provide anonymity. It only increases the *time* before you're located and fingerprinted.

Answer (score 0):

A VM is not used to provide any anonymity because at the end it will have to use the physical interface of its host. Of course it is common to have a distinct IP address on the VM, but you could do the same directly on the host: a network interface card **can** support different addresses - that's the way virtualizers give a new IP to a VM...

And do not forget, the first router that your packets use will maintain an ARP cache that will associate the VM (or spoofed) IP the the physical interface of the host machine, so the network admin will be able to (rather easily) identify it.